# How to save data that I fetched from API, using SharedPreferences in Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, json, kotlin, sharedpreferences, retrofit2

I have used `Retrofit` to make an API call. Now I want to save the data using `SharedPreferences` and to check Previous Promotional Data Method.. Promotional is keyword used by me.

I have created a retrofit instance, declared API services and created a required function in viewmodel class.
Now I have created a method in `getpromotinalDetails` in `FragmentHome` which will be used to save data.
In `onViewCreated` method, `doInitialSetup()` method has been created and in that I will check Previous Promotional Data Method.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    doInitialSetup()
    getPromotionalDetails()
}

private fun getPromotionalDetails() {
    mUserViewModel?.getPromotionalDetails()?.observe(this, Observer { promotionBanner ->
        if (promotionBanner.apiStatus == ApiStatusTypes.SUCCESS) {
            //todo: save data
        } else {
            //Log.d("response", "failed")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that SharedPrefernces are not for saving large text.
I guess you ask how to save data locally in case user does not have internet connection. For that I suggest you take a look at Room Library, Repository pattern(Architecture, you can skip  it). If you haven't done it before it will look scaring but don't worry everyone has face this issue!

Answer (score 0):

**For Andorid**

//these code is for saving json data received from api*

```
try 
{
String dataReceived=jsonObject.setString("data");
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mydata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("saveddata",dataReceived);
editor.commit();
}
catch(Exception e)
{}
```

//these code is for fetching  data stored in shared preference*

```
 SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mydata",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (sharedpreferences.contains("saveddata")) {
            String datafetched=sharedpreferences.getString("saveddata", ""));
        }
```